# Firebase_Ecommerce Purchase

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I have a retail ecommerce app and want to log event for ecommerce purchase.

I want to send the following as parameters: the `names`, `quantity` and `price` of the products purchased.

I know how to log the event for a single product purchase (with event `ECOMMERCE_PURCHASE`) because in this case the event has to supply `name`, `price`, `quantity` of just one product that has been purchased.

But usually customer purchases more than 10 products in single transaction and it may even be 100.

The count is very dynamic.

How do I send the parameters: the names, quantity and price of all products purchased in single transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?  [Enhanced ecommerce using GTM](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v5/enhanced-ecommerce)

Comment: Hey Dan, Thanks a ton!! That was very helpful indeed. I might use some form of loop though along with the instructions in the document shared by you. That way I can automate parameter selections for all products purchased(thats something dynamic and changes at every transaction). Thanks again, really appreciate it!

Comment: Glad to be able to help!